# Why does the inlet pipe into the thermostat housing keep blowing on my 2005 Honda Civic with 1.7L engine?

Tags: honda, cooling-system, repair

I have replaced the O ring. I have replaced the thermostat and cleaned everything. I have checked for anything that might be stopped up or blocked. I have replaced the head gasket, replaced the valve cover gasket because previous blown and leaking oil. There are no leaks. Car does fine until starts heating up and then all of a sudden water starts spurting from the inlet pipe and the pipe has come out some. Its like the thermostat is not opening up causing the pressure to blow out the pipe. But I have replaced the thermostat 3 times. I am at wits end on this and running out of patience. I am about ready to just take out the thermostat and seal up the housing with jb weld and not worry about having a heater. Any suggestions out there would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is too broad to answer. All you will likely get are some general suggestions. Knowing the make, model and engine would be a great start in allowing us to help you. What caused you to change all these items in the first place? Has a leak-down test been done to see if the cooling system will hold pressure?

Comment: I edited my post as suggested. How do you perform a leak-down test? Sounds like something I need to do.

Comment: When you say "the pipe has come out some" ... can you explain that in better detail? The o-ring goes around the thermostat prior to it going into the housing. Then there are two bolts with 10mm heads which holds the housing to the block. There's one radiator hose which attaches to the housing, but that should have been left in place when putting the new thermostat in. Can you confirm the o-ring is going *around* the outside of the thermostat prior to placing it into the housing? Unless it's the wrong size, this about the only way the o-ring would get displaced.

Comment: Check [this video](https://youtu.be/-_4FQEzLcnE).

Comment: A leak-down test pressurizes the cooling system to see if it will hold pressure or "leak down" (part of the test also tests the radiator cap). I use that name from years of other testing, so it may be just called a Cooling System Pressure Tester. Many auto parts stores have a test setup you can rent/borrow. **Just be careful not to open the cooling system while it is hot.**

Comment: What happens if the thermostat is put in backwards?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to throw my hat in the ring and say that you have a cracked engine block. If you start the car COLD with the radiator cap off, and you see bubbles = bad. If you don't see bubbles and it just starts pouring out as the engine warms...= maybe not bad.  This "crack" I'd worry about might also be a warped cylinder head that opens a passage when it heats up. The only other time I've heard somebody replacing this much stuff without cure is when a Nissan cooling system WASN'T bled out properly upon repair, make sure that's not a thing with your Honda. Cheers!